# Answerer un-deleted a deleted answer?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

Can someone explain what happened here?  If I am reading it right, the timeline for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49502688/7311767) looks like the OP was able to undelete a deleted answer.

The answer eventually got deleted a second time, but how did an answerer undelete their deleted answer?  (Or am I just reading the timeline wrong?)

Timeline:

[image]